# How do I print a twig variable inside a JavaScript in a twig file

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I have a twig file of a custom module. It has a `<script></script>` section and I need to print a twig variable inside that section. How do I do this?

```
{{ set twigVariable = '123456' }}

<script>
    function myFunc() {
        var myJsVar = {{ twigVariable }};
    }
</script>
```

The variable does not print when I write like above.

Comment: Don’t do this. Use drupalSettings, construct values in a module or preprocess and attach them.

Comment: Is there a reason that you say don't do this? @Kevin

Comment: Because it is bad practice to mix up theming and functional parts as JavaScript in a template. You should keep your templates clean and use template pre-processing to attach any scripts or script settings required by your frontend features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll spare to tell that it's a bad practice to add custom script blocks to templates, and just point out the error(s):

(1) To set the variable content, you have to wrap `set` into a `{% %}` block, not `{{ }}`.

(2) You most probably want the value as JavaScript string, so don't forget to wrap it in `" "`.

This sums up to

```
{% set twigVariable = '123456' %}

<script>
  function myFunc() {
    var myJsVar = "{{ twigVariable }}";
  }
</script>
```

Which should be working just fine.

Comment: This is not going to work because of the cache.